# Why does the CdnFallbackExpression generate a version-less bundle?

Tags: asp.net, caching, bundle, cdn, web-optimization

Typically, all bundles generated by System.Web.Optimization are given versions in their query parameters. However, if you specify a `CdnPath` and `CdnFallbackExpression` value, the `src` attribute in the fallback `<script>` is left without a version. Is there a reason for this I'm not understanding, or is this a bug in the code?

Comment: Can you post your bundle config?